# How to optimize concurrent restoration of multiple VLDB user DBs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

For purposes of optimizing native sql backup (full & differential) restore times, can you run concurrent restore commands for two separate VLDB native backups (10+ tb a piece) on a secondary sql server?  If so what are the recommendations for optimizing this process (sql version, san configuration, processors, memory, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have to build your own tests for this one - there will be relatively few people who do this on a regular basis - (but happy to be proved wrong).

Is there a reason why you can't use VSS / SAN Snapshots to meet this requirement ?

Some standard best practices are going to help, i.e. use multiple backups files, use backup compression.

regarding restoring 2 VLDBs simultaneously I would try and ensure that each database has its own separate IO systems - so probably a Diskgroup & dedicated controller on the SAN rather than just a separate set of LUNs, but talk to your storage admins as SANs vary widely with regards to best configuration.

Comment: Good idea on the VSS / SAN Snapshots!